# How to route transmission traffic

Tags: wireless, ethernet, iptables, transmission, torrent-client

Trying to get Transmission to only use my wifi interface (wlan0), while everything else uses ethernet (eth0). I was able to bind Transmission to the wlan0 IP but can't get it to work unless I disconnect the ethernet connection. How do I get this to work while keeping my ethernet connect active?

Comment: What / how did you bind it to wlan

Comment: I'm using transmission setting "bind-address-ipv4".

Answer (score 0):

Problem is default gateway. Try to add second default gw with more metric.

```
sudo route add default gw xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx metric 200
```

`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` - in command represent ip address of wireless interface from router

Output from command will show two gw

```
xxx@xxx ~ $ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         213.xxx.xx.xxx  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         192.xxx.x.xxx   0.0.0.0         UG    200    0        0 wlan0
192.xxx.x.x     *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
213.xxx.xx.x    *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Just tried your suggestion but its still not working. Here's a link on what my route table looks like http://pastebin.com/Sggvq8Qu